# PostgreSQL: default constraint names

Tags: postgresql, naming-conventions, constraints

When creating a table in PostgreSQL, default constraint names will assigned if not provided:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    a integer,
    b integer,
    UNIQUE (a, b)
);
```

But using `ALTER TABLE` to add a constraint it seems a name is mandatory:

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT my_explicit_constraint_name UNIQUE (a, b);
```

This has caused some naming inconsistencies on projects I've worked on, and prompts the following questions:

1. Is there a simple way to add a constraint to an extant table with the name it would have received if added during table creation?
2. If not, should default names be avoided altogether to prevent inconsistencies?

Comment: I make it a rule to avoid default names for just this reason - you end up with the situation where in every deployment the constraints have different names.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) is pretty clear about this ("*tableconstraint: This form adds a new constraint to a table using the same syntax as CREATE TABLE.*")

So you can simply run:

```
ALTER TABLE example ADD UNIQUE (a, b);
```

Comment: Ah! I was mistakenly including `CONSTRAINT` like `ALTER TABLE example ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (a, b);` and getting errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 390):

The standard names for indexes in PostgreSQL are:

`{tablename}_{columnname(s)}_{suffix}`

where the suffix is one of the following:

- `pkey` for a Primary Key constraint
- `key` for a Unique constraint
- `excl` for an Exclusion constraint
- `idx` for any other kind of index
- `fkey` for a Foreign key
- `check` for a Check constraint

Standard suffix for sequences is

- `seq` for all sequences

Proof of your UNIQUE-constraint:

> NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / UNIQUE will
>   create implicit index
>   "example_a_b_key" for table "example"

Comment: Very useful, thanks! Worth adding that foreign keys use the suffix `fkey` and that multi-column foreign key constraints only seem to include the first column name.

Comment: @IanMackinnon, This should be the best answer!

Comment: This info is gold! You can confirm these by running e.g `CREATE TABLE mytable (mycolumn numeric UNIQUE);`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8674640/14731 if you want to override the default constraint name.

Comment: I don't think this is always useful, I liked this article talking about naming conventions here: https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for when googling "postgresql index naming conventions"

Comment: What will the generated name be for the second index on a column? Will it be `idx2`?

Comment: @IanMackinnon This was changed/fixed in version 12. It's mentioned at the end of section E.3.3.3 in [the release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html)

Comment: @FrankHeikens This is very useful, I would like to know is there any official document or reference to cite??

Comment: @MichaelHewson I can't find section `E3.3.3` :( The link above seems like ends of `E.3.2. Changes`.

Comment: @someone ah sorry, I guess I meant the end of E.4.3.3 Utility Commands. It's the last bullet item before E.4.3.4 Data Types: "Use all key columns' names when selecting default constraint names for foreign keys (Peter Eisentraut)"

Comment: @MichaelHewson thanks! Looks like the document update very frequently.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! It would be cool to have some examples indexes under each one just so we can see it in action. For foreign keys, is the table name the name of the table the foreign key is in or the table of the key it is referencing

For example, if there is a `user_id` foreign key in a `user_media` table. Is the foreign key then `user_media_user_id_fkey`?

Comment: Using PostgreSQL version 11, I observed that the default name of a primary key constraint is always `{tablename}_pkey`, and does not include the name of the column or columns used in the primary key.

Comment: Using PostgreSQL version 11, I observed that the default name of a foreign key constraint is always `{tablename}_{first columnname}_fkey`,.  i.e., regardless of how many columns are used in the foreign key, only the name of the first column is used..

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm looking for documentation on how long constraint names get truncated, would be nice to have in this answer if it's explicitly documented anywhere.

Comment: For unique index, maybe `uidx` is more suitable.