# PostgreSQL: is it possible to provide custom name for PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, primary-key, constraints, unique-key

When I write:

```
 CREATE TABLE accounts (

     username varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,
```

I get primary key named:

```
accounts_pkey
```

Is it possible to assign my own custom name, for instance "accounts_primary_key"?

Same story about `UNIQUE`.

I couldn't find it in PostgreSQL documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The trick is the `CONSTRAINT` part in the `column_constraint` section of `CREATE TABLE`. Example:

```
> create table x(xx text constraint xxxx primary key);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "xxxx" for table "x"
CREATE TABLE
```

This works for all kind of constraints, including `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE`.

See the docs of [CREATE TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html) for details.

Comment: I suppose I need to study Postgres docs more thoroughly. :-) Thanks!

Comment: Does this work for `EXCLUDE` constraints? I can't figure out how to name those explicitly as part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @bjmc: Reading the actual docs `EXCLUDE` is a table-constraint not a column constraint. So the syntax is `create table x(xx text, constraint xxxx exclude ...);` -- note the `,` between the column definition and the table-constraint.