# confusing error message on constraint error

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Ecto is throwing me the following error:

```
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * unique: res_users_login_key

If you would like to convert this constraint into an error, please
call unique_constraint/3 in your changeset and define the proper
constraint name. The changeset defined the following constraints:

    * unique: res_users_login_index
```

Do I understand correctly that the actual name of the constraint in postgresql determines if the unique_constraint/3 function is successful or not? Just for reference, in postgreSQL the constraint is defined as follows:

```
Indexes:
    "res_users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "res_users_login_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (login)
```

so `_key` and not `_index`.

I call the constraint function as follows:

```
 changeset |> unique_constraint(:login)
```

So, how do I make this work?

Comment: Try `|> unique_constraint(:login, [name: :res_users_login_index])`.

Comment: Do you mean: `|> unique_constraint(:login, [name: :res_users_login_key])`?

Comment: Oops yes, `_key`. `_index` is the incorrect name used by default since you hadn't specified a `name`.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107915/postgresql-default-constraint-names/4108266#4108266 `_index` seems to be an inappropriate default doesn't it? Seems `_key` would be better for unique constraints.

Comment: They probably default to that because `unique_index` in Ecto migrations use the `_index` suffix for the index names by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constraint name used by Ecto when one is not given is `#{table_name}_#{field}_index`. Your table is probably named `res_users`, and the field is `login`, which is why Ecto uses the constraint name `res_users_login_index`, which is incorrect in your case. You'll need to explicitly specify the name `res_users_login_key` in the call to `unique_constraint`:

```
|> unique_constraint(:login, [name: :res_users_login_key])
```