# PostgreSQL. Is it possible to customize default naming?

Tags: postgresql, naming-conventions

We have our long-used internal db naming conventions. For example: suffix for indexes is "_ix", for foreign key - "_fk".

These conventions are conflicting with [default postgresql naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4108266): "_idx" for index and "_fkey" for foreign key.

For example. If i create index and don't define index name explicit like this `CREATE INDEX ON a (id);` then i'll get such index name: **a_id_idx**. But according to our conventions, which are used not only for postgresql, there must be **a_id_ix**.

The best way would be to change autogenerated naming pattern to match our conventions. Seems it should be simple but i can't find how it can be done.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you want non-default names, set nondefault names.

Comment: [I still think it is a bad idea,but] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterindex.html `ALTER INDEX [ IF EXISTS ] name RENAME TO new_name;`

Comment: @CraigRinger, there are 2 reasons why i searching ability to change the defaults:
1. There is serial type (quite convenient) generating sequence with name {table_name}_{column_name}_seq and i can't define name explicitly without manual sequence creation
2. It is wrong to forbid using autogeneration at all if there is alternative.

But if i can't change the postgres defaults at global level then probably i will have to add some rules in our conventions that prohibit the use of serial type and some other features.

Comment: You can't change the PostgreSQL name generation.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON a (id);
```

Comment: In some cases i can't define explicit name. For example: for serial column type postgresql generates sequence with name {table_name}_{column_name}_seq, but i need {table_name}_seq.

Comment: @keddok: yes you can: `create sequence some_table_seq; create table some_table (id integer default nextval('some_table_seq')); alter sequence some_table_seq owned by some_table.id;`

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name. But  understand that there are other ways. I don't wanna prohobit the use of serial type, it is quite convenient. I just wanna to change defaults in postgresql.

Comment: @keddok: then you need to change the Postgres source and compile your own version